# How to deploy spring boot app which uses postgres database on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I used this command to deploy my spring boot application

```
sudo kubectl run mykubernetes-springboot 
--image=glgelopfalcon/springboot_docker_maven:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --port=8080
```

Deplyment is created but when i check logs by

```
kubectl logs pod podname
```

It giving exception as

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I installed postgres on my local machine.

Test for semah answer
postgres.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-svc
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 10.0.2.2
```

kubectl get svc gives

```
postgres-svc       ExternalName   <none>           10.0.2.2      <none>           2m12s
```

Spring boot app deployement logs give

```
IOException occurred while connecting to postgres-svc.external.svc:5432
java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-svc.external.svc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to connect to DB installed on your local machine and not in kubernetes it is normal to have this error because localhost inside pod this not means your local machine , so can you tell where your db is running ?

try this as you confirmed that you run in local :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: mysql-db-svc
spec:
ports:
- port: 5432
```

and add endpoint to this service :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
name: mysql-db-svc
subsets:
- addresses:
 - ip: 10.0.2.2
 ports:
 - port: 5432
```

then access it using :

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://mysql-db-svc/databasename
```

Comment: db is running on my local machine not on any pod

Comment: my db is postgres

Comment: what is the problem if it is postgres

Comment: Okay i will create such svc file ..then run kubectl create -f svcfilename.yaml right?

Comment: which iP should i use to db url?url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

Comment: yes ,also in your spring boot app you should replace localhost with 
url=jdbc:postgresql://mysql-db-svc.external.svc:5432/postgres

Comment: what is externalName=10.0.2.2 ?

Comment: The reason why we use 10.0.2.2 is because it's the special alias to our host loopback interface (aka 127.0.0.1).
by the way have you tested the solution ?

Comment: can you please edit yaml file and write for postgres db

Comment: i added the output of you answer

Comment: Getting same result of unknown host exception. I think from pod i am not able to ping db_server

Comment: otherwise run you db inside k8s

Comment: Actually here is my problem .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455653/cant-ping-postgres-pod-from-another-pod-in-kubernetes/56456377?noredirect=1#comment99508263_56456377

Comment: Yes,,My DNS was also problem and your solution using this solves my dynamic IP problem