# Can't ping postgres pod from another pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I created one busy pod to test db connection by following yaml

pod.yaml

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: marks-dummy-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: marks-dummy-pod
      image: djtijare/ubuntuping:v1
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-ec", "while :; do echo '.'; sleep 5 ; done"]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Dockerfile used :-

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
CMD bash
```

I create service as

postgresservice.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: postgressvc
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 5432
   targetPort: 5432
```

Endpoint for created service as

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: postgressvc
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 172.31.6.149
   ports:
     - port: 5432
```

Then i ran **ping 172.31.6.149** inside pod (kubectl exec -it mark-dummy-pod bash) but not working.(ping localhost is working)

output of  **kubectl get pods,svc,ep -o wide**

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/marks-dummy-pod                        1/1     Running   0          43m     192.168.1.63   ip-172-31-11-87   <none>           <none>


NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
service/postgressvc        ClusterIP   10.107.58.81     <none>        5432/TCP         33m     <none>


NAME                         ENDPOINTS           AGE
endpoints/postgressvc        172.31.6.149:5432   32m
```

**Output for answer by P Ekambaram**

**kubectl get pods,svc,ep -o wide** gives

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP             NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/postgres-855696996d-w6h6c   1/1     Running   0          44s    192.168.1.66   ip-172-31-11-87   <none>           <none>


NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE    SELECTOR
service/postgres        NodePort    10.110.203.204   <none>        5432:31076/TCP   44s    app=postgres



 NAME                      ENDPOINTS           AGE
endpoints/postgres        192.168.1.66:5432   44s
```

Comment: Hi, what kind of error message you are you getting ? can you run `kubectl get pods,svc,ep`

Comment: No error message for command ping 172.31.6.149 as it getting hanged ,then i do ctlr + c gives 100% packet loss

Comment: I added output of **kubectl get pods,svc,ep** in question above ..please check

Comment: Sorry, can you update the question with the result of this commend `kubectl get pods,svc,ep -o wide` it will provide more info

Comment: Done ..i added output of  **kubectl get pods,svc,ep -o wide**

Comment: why is your pod having IPs from different CIDR, and where is the postgre pod ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194474/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-dhanraj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem was in my DNS pod in namespace=kube-system

I just create new kubernetes setup and make sure that DNS is working

For new setup refer to my answer of another question

[How to start kubelet service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463783/how-to-start-kubelet-service)?

Answer (score 0):

postgres pod is missing?

did you create endpoint object or was it auto generated?

share the pod definition YAML

you shouldnt be creating endpoint. it is wrong. follow the below deployment for postgres.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:11
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-data
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-data
          emptyDir:
---       
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

undeploy postgres service and endpoint and deploy the above YAML.
it should work

why NODE ip is prefixed with ip-

[image]

Comment: I already shared file named pod.yaml... I created endpoint object as all yaml files are  added in question

Comment: So using what ip should i ping to this database from my **marks-dummy-pod** pod?

Comment: kubectl get pods,svc,ep -o wide

Comment: share the output

Comment: I added output for you answer

Comment: pod ip is 192.168.1.66

Comment: you should be able to ping 192.168.1.66  from marks-dummy-pod pod. check and confirm

Comment: No.. ping 192.168.1.66
PING 192.168.1.66 (192.168.1.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.66 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4080ms

Comment: redeploy marks-dummy-pod pod.you should be able to ping  192.168.1.66 and 10.110.203.204

Comment: I already did..that's my problem can't able to ping any ip-address or www.google.com from pod

Comment: look at the NODE column. it shows the node ip as ip-172-31-11-87. can you ping ip-172-31-11-87

Comment: I am able to do **ping 172.31.11.87**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194479/discussion-between-p-ekambaram-and-dhanraj).

Answer (score 0):

you should create deployment for your database and then make a service that target this deployment and then ping using this service why ping with ip ?

Comment: I tried...but now i think problem is with my kube-dns pod