# How to start kubelet service?

Tags: kubernetes

I ran command
**systemctl stop kubelet**
then try to start it
**systemctl start kubelet**

but can't able to start it

here is the output of **systemctl status kubelet**

```
 kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-06-05 15:35:34 UTC; 7s ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
  Process: 31697 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 31697 (code=exited, status=255)
```

Because of this i am not able to run any kubectl command

example **kubectl get pods** gives

```
The connection to the server 172.31.6.149:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So i need to reset kubelete service
Here are the step :-

1. check status of your docker service.
   If stoped,start it by cmd `sudo systemctl start docker`.
   If not installed installed it
   `#yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl docker`
2. Make swap off by #swapoff -a
3. Now reset kubeadm by #kubeadm reset
4. Now try #kudeadm init
   after that check #systemctl status kubelet
   it will be working

Check nodes
kubectl get nodes
if Master Node is not ready ,refer following
To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

if you not able to create pod ..check dns
kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
if dns pods are in pending state
i.e you need to use network service
i used calico

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Now your master node is ready .. now you can deploy pod

Answer (score 6):

### Worked

Need to disable swap using **swapoff -a**
then,
try to start it **systemctl start kubelet**

Answer (score 1):

If youre using containerd, you have to start the containerd service instead crio

```
swapoff -a
systemctl start crio
systemctl start kubelet.service
```