# Kubernetes Cluster master/ Worker Nodes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to create a Kubernetes cluster,  this cluster will contain 3 nodes
Master Nodes, where I Installed and configured kubeadm , kubelete, and  installed my system there (which is web application developed by laravel ),
the worker nodes is joined to the master without any problem ,
and I deployed my system to PHP-fpm pods and  created services and horizontal  Pods Autoscaling
this is my service:

```
PHP             LoadBalancer   10.108.218.232   <pending>     9000:30026/TCP   15h   app=php
```

this is my pods

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
qsinavphp-5b67996888-9clxp   1/1     Running   0          40m   10.244.0.4    taishan             <none>           <none>
qsinavphp-5b67996888-fnv7c   1/1     Running   0          43m   10.244.0.12   kubernetes-master   <none>           <none>
qsinavphp-5b67996888-gbtdw   1/1     Running   0          40m   10.244.0.3    taishan             <none>           <none>
qsinavphp-5b67996888-l6ghh   1/1     Running   0          33m   10.244.0.2    taishan             <none>           <none>
qsinavphp-5b67996888-ndbc8   1/1     Running   0          43m   10.244.0.11   kubernetes-master   <none>           <none>
qsinavphp-5b67996888-qgdbc   1/1     Running   0          43m   10.244.0.10   kubernetes-master   <none>           <none>
qsinavphp-5b67996888-t97qm   1/1     Running   0          43m   10.244.0.13   kubernetes-master   <none>           <none>
qsinavphp-5b67996888-wgrzb   1/1     Running   0          43m   10.244.0.14   kubernetes-master   <none>           <none>
```

the worker nondes is taishan , and the master is Kubernetes-master.
and this is  my nginx config which is sending request to php service

```
server {
 listen 80;
  listen 443  ssl;
    server_name k8s.example.com;
    root /var/www/html/Test/project-starter/public;
        ssl_certificate "/var/www/cert/example.cer";
        ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/cert/example.key";

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;
 # if ($scheme = http) {
 #   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
 # }
   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES25>
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
         fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_index            index.php;
         fastcgi_pass             10.108.218.232:9000;
         include                  fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
         fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
}
}
```

the problem is I have 3 pods on  the worker node and 5 pods on the master node, but no request going to the worker's pods  all  request is going to the master,
both of my nodes are in ready status

```
NAME                STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kubernetes-master   Ready    control-plane,master   15h   v1.20.4   10.14.0.58    <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS   5.4.0-70-generic   docker://19.3.8
taishan             Ready    <none>                 79m   v1.20.5   10.14.2.66    <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS   5.4.0-42-generic   docker://19.3.8
```

this is my kubectl describe nodes php result

```
Name:                     php
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   tier=backend
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=php
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.108.218.232
IPs:                      10.108.218.232
Port:                     <unset>  9000/TCP
TargetPort:               9000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30026/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.10:9000,10.244.0.11:9000,10.244.0.12:9000 + 7 more...
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                -------
  Normal  Type    48m   service-controller  ClusterIP -> LoadBalancer
```

this is  my yaml file which I am using to create the deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: php
  name: qsinavphp
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: taishan-php-fpm
          image: starking8b/taishanphp:last
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000

          volumeMounts:


            - name: qsinav-nginx-config-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
              subPath: www.conf
            - name: qsinav-nginx-config-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini
              subPath: php-memory
            - name: qsinav-php-config-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production
              subPath: php.ini
            - name: qsinav-php-config-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
              subPath: php.ini
            - name: qsinav-php-config-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
              subPath: php-fpm.conf

            - name: qsinav-www-storage
              mountPath: /var/www/html/Test/qSinav-starter
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 4048m

            requests:
              cpu: 4048m



      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
        - name: qsinav-www-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: qsinav-pv-www-claim
        - name: qsinav-nginx-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: qsinav-nginx-config

        - name: qsinav-php-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: qsinav-php-config
```

and this is my service yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php
  labels:
    tier: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: php

  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I am not sure where is my error , so please help to solve this problem

Comment: Its because your service is not started properly. > LoadBalancer   10.108.218.232   <pending>

pending state means, it has a problem with service.

Comment: thanks for reply , I updated the question with the service describe  , but it is not showing any error inside it  please check the question again

Comment: I am not sure, what should I do then? please help me

Comment: Can you post your pod deployment and service manifests.?

Comment: yes sure I ll update the question with them

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram hello sir  , I just updated the question please have a look , I added the yaml file in the last of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the problem was with flannel network , it was not able to make connection between nodes  , so I solved it by installing weave plugin which is working fine now
by applying this command

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added from basic baremetal k8 installation

```
##### Creating ssh keys

From master node

`ssh-keygen`

Copy content in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Login to other servers and paste this copied part into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Follow these steps in all servers. Master and worker.

`sudo apt-get install python`

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

Adding Ansible 

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt-get install ansible -y`

[Reference](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-ansible-on-ubuntu-server-18-04/)

### Install Kubernetes

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install docker.io`

`sudo systemctl enable docker`

`curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add`

`sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"`

`sudo apt-get install kubeadm kubelet kubectl`

`sudo apt-mark hold kubeadm kubelet kubectl`

For more details please [refer](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu)

### Installing Kubespray

`git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray.git`

`cd kubespray`

`sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

`cp -rfp inventory/sample inventory/mycluster`

`declare -a IPS=(10.10.1.3 10.10.1.4 10.10.1.5)` 

Please put your IP addresses here separated with a space.

`CONFIG_FILE=inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml python3 contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py ${IPS[@]}`

`ansible-playbook -i inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml  --become --become-user=root cluster.yml`

For none root user access 
`ansible-playbook -i inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml --become --become-user=root cluster.yml --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=password"`

This will take around 15mins to run successfully. If `root` user ssh is not working properly, this will fail. Please check key sharing step again.

[10 Simple stepms](https://dzone.com/articles/kubespray-10-simple-steps-for-installing-a-product)

[Add a node to existing cluster](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/containers/kubernetes/how-to-add-workers-to-kubernetes-clusters/)

[kubelet debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463783/how-to-start-kubelet-service)

### Possible Errors

`kubectl get nodes`

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Perform followings as normal user (none root user)

`mkdir -p $HOME/.kube`

`sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config`

`sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config`

If you are in worker node, you will have to use `scp` to get `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` from master node. Master node may have this problem, if so please do these steps locally using normal user.

[Refer](https://www.edureka.co/community/18633/error-saying-connection-server-localhost-refused-specify)

## Installing MetalLB

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.3/manifests/namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.3/manifests/metallb.yaml
# On first install only
kubectl create secret generic -n metallb-system memberlist --from-literal=secretkey="$(openssl rand -base64 128)"


[Official Installation guide](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/)

### Configuring L2 config

sachith@master:~$ cat << EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.19-192.168.1.29    # Preferred IP range.
EOF
```

Verify installation success using : `kubectl describe configmap config -n metallb-system`

This will install two components.

- Controller : Responsible for assigning IPs.
- Speaker    : Facilitate services to navigate through LB.

Comment: no I am not using minikube  ,  so , what should I do ? as I am not using it  , I followed this documentation to install kubernetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

Comment: Do you have cloud based cluster or baremetal?

Comment: actually in the company wh have 3 Taishan servers , they are now in local, I am trying to create Kubernetes clustering between these servers , so I followed the link  which I sent to u ,in order to create a master node on one of these servers, and then I applied the join command on another server

Comment: can we have a chat ? so maybe u will have good vision about what I am trying to do

Comment: @Muhammadahmad yes, we can.

Comment: sorry I am trying to create chat but  it seems  no Privileges to do that

Comment: do u have any suggestions sir?

Comment: Nope, please try some online forums. I will update answer later

Comment: hi bro, thanks for your help and your asking, yes actually the problem was with flannel network, it was not able to make the connection between nodes, so I solved it by installing the weave plugin which is working fine now